# jQuery, stopping clicking during animations

Tags: animation, jquery

:D

I am currently having much trouble with a jQuery animation. Basically, a button click will quickly start a short animation and collapse a sidebar, widening the main content box to full width (and back again if wanted). The issue is that with quick consecutive clicks, the layout goes all crazy. I have tried this condition:

```
if (!$(this).is(":animated"))
{
// Code
}
```

But it doesn't work. So I have tried .off(), and it shuts off, but I cannot find out how to turn it back .on(). Can someone help me please? Here is what I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var $button     =   $("a#toggle");
var $content    =   $("div#index_main-content");
var $sidebar    =   $("div#sidebar");

    // Disable quicky clicky
    $button.click(function() {

        $button.off().delay(1000).on();

    });

    // Hide sidebar
    $button.toggle(function sidebarToggle() {
        $sidebar.fadeOut(500, function() {

            $content.animate({width: '100%'}, 500, function() {

                $button.attr("title", "Click to show the sidebar!").addClass("hiding").removeClass("showing");

            });

        });

    },

    // Show sidebar
    function sidebarToggle() {
        $content.animate({width: '69.5%'}, 500, function() {

            $sidebar.fadeIn(500, function() {

                $button.attr("title", "Click to hide the sidebar!").addClass("showing").removeClass("hiding");

            });

        });

    });

});
</script>

<div id="index_content">

    <a title="Click to hide the sidebar" class="showing" id="toggle"></a>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar: float-right/width-28.5% -->
    </div>

    <div id="index_main-content">
        <!-- Content: float-left/width-69.5% -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, there is a live demo [here](http://www.littlebigplanetfanatic.com/community/). Like I said before, for some reason, the .on() does not happen. :(

Thank you. :)

Comment: Where are you putting `.is(':animated')`?

Comment: why do you redefine sidebarToggle?

Comment: I just wanted a name. :P and I didn't use .is.. because that was a previous test, and it did nothing

Comment: It would be great if you solved the issue to choose the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using stop before issuing the animation the second time, for example:

```
$content.stop().animate(
```

This will stop and previous animations before starting the new one.

Also use true in the stop statement to cancel other animation and complete the animations.

```
$content.stop(true,true).animate(
```

See:

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 1):

[stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the current animation, 
clear the animation queue and go to the end of the animation .stop(true,true)

or

- turn the button to OFF before you start the animation
- turn the button to ON within the animation callback function, so that
  is turned on again after the animation finished

OR more easy

```
<div id="index_content">

    <a title="Click to hide the sidebar" class="showing" id="toggle">Click me</a>

    <div id="sidebar">sidebar
        <!-- Sidebar: float-right/width-28.5% -->
    </div>

    <div id="index_main-content">content
        <!-- Content: float-left/width-69.5% -->
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('#sidebar:visible').fadeOut('slow')
    $('#sidebar:hidden').fadeIn('slow')
  })
})
```

take a look@
http://jsfiddle.net/jdFrR/

Comment: Thank you very much! The callback .on() didn't work, but the hide and show worked great! :D

Answer (score 1):

`$content.stop(true,true).animate({ //code });`